# Android NFC: Get communicating device details

Tags: android, nfc

I have an app which uses NFC (P2P NFC) to communicate between two android devices. App works fine. I want to know if i can details other receiving device such as device id and type.
how do i get which device is doing the NFC communication?

Thanks

Comment: So you have yourself written an app?

Comment: Yes i have a working app which does P2P NFC communication. I would like to get the device details of those two devices such as device unique id, type.

Answer (score -1):

That cannot be done using the built-in Android NFC P2P functionality, doing only NFC communication. However if you use NFC to pair the devices, you could exchange that information using out-of-band channels, like bluetooth. Obiously you could add device type info to any NFC  payload, but you would not really be getting that info via the NFC communication (protocols).